# How do I pass the required jQuery object down into inside objects?

Tags: jquery

```
    jQuery.fn.extend({
    fillCurrency : (function() {
        $this = jQuery(this);

        function _usd(string1) {
            $this.text("$" + parseFloat(string1).toFixed(2));

            return $this;
        }

        return {
            usd : _usd
        };
    })()
});


var text = 2;
jQuery("#total").fillCurrency.usd(text);


<p id="total"></p>
```

Tried several options and I think I have now come close. The issues is now Object [object global] has no method 'createDocumentFragment'. Does someone know what the issue is here?

Comment: What is the question? What do you want to pass and where?

Comment: -1 At least check if you have typos in your code before asking a question

Comment: The Typo was done when putting it into the code block. It is correct in the actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
Currency : function() {
        var $this = this;

        var _Fill = {
            usd : function(string) {
                $this.text("$" + parseFloat(string).toFixed(2));

                return $this;
   }
        }

        var _Get = {
            usd : function(string) {
                $this.text("$" + parseFloat(string).toFixed(2));

                return $this;
   }
        }

        return {
            Fill : _Fill,
            Get : _Get
        }
    }
});
```

This will pass the jQuery object down into the inside objects for things such as a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend passing the currency in parameter of the function `fillCurrency` then in your code you have a **typo**:

```
jQuery("#total").fillCurency.usd(text);
```

should be

```
jQuery("#total").fillCurrency.usd(text);
```

but even if you fix your typo it will not give you what you want

This is what I suggest:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.fillCurrency = function (currency, value) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (currency === "usd") {
                $(this).text(parseFloat(value).toFixed(2));
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

$(function () {
    var text = 2;
    $("p#total").fillCurrency("usd", text);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pWcBD/

Comment: This idea is to have more beyond the "usd". Can you pass the jQuery object down only once?